# How to keep a local ~/bin folder up to date with updates from various Github repositories?

Tags: updates, scripts, github

`~/bin` contains a number of scripts that I downloaded from various Github repositories for which the Ubuntu default repositories do not provide the latest version and/or PPAs do not exist.

What are good ways to keep all these scripts **automatically** up to date and synchronised with the most recent versions from their respective Github repositories?

Comment: How are you keeping them up to date manually at the moment?

Comment: Dear @andrew.46, from time to time I manually download the latest version through my web browser and replace the old script using Nautilus file manager. I was wondering whether someone else had already created a very widely used package to automatise this as I had imagined this to be a very frequent problem (since Ubuntu doesn't always ship the latest software of any kind of small script).

Comment: A script that checks for updates and `git clone`s them every day or so is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simple solution

What you want to do essentially is to run `git fetch && git pull` from inside each one of the repository folders inside `~/bin`. The simplest way is to add this command to Startup Applications:

```
find /home/user/bin  -type d -exec sh -c 'cd {} && git fetch && git pull' \;  2> /dev/null
```

Note, that `/home/user/bin` must be full path to your `~/bin` folder.

---

#### Python script

But if you want a dedicated utility to this task, here's a python script that updates everything in your `~/bin` recursively.  Usage is simple - run it from terminal as `python git_updater.py` and it will take care of the rest. That same command can be even added as entry to Startup Applications to [run the script each time you log in](https://askubuntu.com/q/48321/295286)

The script source is below, and is also available on my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Author: Serg Kolo
# Date: 10/21/2016
# Written for: https://askubuntu.com/q/759058/295286
from __future__ import print_function
import subprocess
import os

def run_cmd(cmdlist,workdir):
     """ utility: reusable function for 
         running external commands """
     new_env = dict(os.environ)
     new_env['LC_ALL'] = 'C'
     try:
         stdout = subprocess.check_output(
                    cmdlist, 
                    env=new_env,
                    cwd=workdir
         )
     except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
         pass
     else:
         if stdout:
             return stdout

def is_behind(cwd):
    """ simple wrapper for checking
        git status output
    """
    fetch = run_cmd(['git','fetch','origin','master'],cwd)
    status = run_cmd(['git','status'],cwd)
    if 'Your branch is behind' in status.decode():
        return True

def update(cwd):
    print('> previous commit:')
    print(run_cmd(['git','--no-pager','log','-1'],cwd).decode())
    print(run_cmd(['git','pull'],cwd).decode())
    print('> latest commit:')
    print(run_cmd(['git','--no-pager','log','-1'],cwd).decode())

def main():
    root_dir = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'bin/')
    base_cmd = ['git','--no-pager']
    first_args = ['status']
    second_args = ['log','-1']
    third_args = ['pull']

    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(root_dir):
        for dir in dirs:
            top_dir = os.path.join(root,dir)
            git_dir = os.path.join(top_dir,'.git')
            if os.path.exists(git_dir):
                print('WORKING REPOSITORY:' + top_dir)
                if is_behind(top_dir):
                    print('repository is behind, will update')
                    update(top_dir)
                else:
                    print('not behind, skipped')
                print('-'*80)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

---

#### Script Demo

```
$ python git_updater.py                                                       
WORKING REPOSITORY:/home/xieerqi/bin/sergrep
From https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
repository is behind, will update
> previous commit:
commit ba629ef71c4d2bfe329b8ebe5f48d1ce21e76ebc
Author: SergKolo <1047481448@qq.com>
Date:   Wed Aug 24 21:22:06 2016 -0600

    fixed sending sigterm to process

Updating ba629ef..dd0c962
Fast-forward
 disable_super_key.py   |   2 +-
 git_updater.py         |  61 ++++++++++++
 launcherctl.py         | 162 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 single_window_expo.py  | 138 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 windowctrl.py          | 258 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 xml_wallpaper_maker.py | 152 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 6 files changed, 772 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
 create mode 100644 git_updater.py
 create mode 100755 launcherctl.py
 create mode 100755 single_window_expo.py
 create mode 100755 windowctrl.py
 create mode 100755 xml_wallpaper_maker.py

> latest commit:
commit dd0c9627392540df7c4230e7898cb9e55adc7083
Author: SergKolo <1047481448@qq.com>
Date:   Fri Oct 21 02:37:01 2016 -0600

    git updater script

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WORKING REPOSITORY:/home/xieerqi/bin/PythonStuff
From https://github.com/mnovits1/PythonStuff
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
not behind, skipped
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```